# Best place to save Java configuration information

Tags: java

I am writing a library which uses some configurations. These configuration will not change frequently but will possible change in the future. Therefore I don't want to hard code them in the code.

What is the best way of doing this for a Java library? One possible solution is to inject it and hard code them in a DI configuration file I assume. But this requires code change as well.

What is the most typical way of doing this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

- Add the default configuration as an embedded resource file to the library jar
- Then the user can override the file adding a resource with the same path to the classpath

As file format you can use the [Java Properties File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html).

And you can load it in this way

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("name-of-your-prop-file.properties"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Java Util [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) is a great tool for configuration. You can have the file embed in the jar, if you want to, and load it using [`getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) method.